# DRF filter/search return everything?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently doing self project inventory app and trying to implement filter and search.

what I've done

#views.py

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters    

class ListInventories(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = Inventory
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name']
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'stock']

    def get(self, request):

        inventories = Inventory.objects.all()
        serializer = InventorySerializers(inventories, many=True)
        return Response({'inventories': serializer.data})


class InventoryDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        inventories = Inventory.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = InventorySerializers(inventories)
        return Response({'inventory': serializer.data})
```

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_filters',
    ...
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

in url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/inventory?name=para
```

I tried `?search=para` and `?search=anynonsense` . and the DRF would always return everything.

just for the sake of clarification here is the screenshot(the total of item is just 3 for now, but even then filter/search should work):

[image: DRF]

I expect the filter/search to function at least on a minimal level. What do I do to make this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I solved the problem.

It is the `get` method that keep returning everything. I commented out the method `get` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the error:

```
class ListInventories(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = Inventory
    
    # You are settings search filter here
    * filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]

    search_fields = ['name']
    
    # and overriding it here, that's why search is not working
    * filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    filterset_fields = ['name', 'stock']
```

it should be `filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]`

Comment: I tried this, still not working, any other ?

Comment: In the image you have provided, there's no button for `django-filter`, is `django-filter` installed ?